# How to remove data from a single array after comparing it with an array from a database?

Tags: php, arrays

So currently, I have a single array ($array1) that I want to compare with an array ($array2) that I created by retrieving data from the database. Technically speaking, $array2 is multidimensional since I used a while loop with mysqli_fetch_assoc. Is there any way to compare these two arrays with each other? My end goal is to compare these two arrays, and to only remove the data from the single array ($array1) when there is a mismatch. By that, I mean only to remove the data that doesn't match with $array2.

For example:
$array1 = Array ( [0] => cookies [1] => chicken [2] => tesla )
$array2 = Array ( [name] => tesla ) Array ( [name] => bmw ) Array ( [name] => opel )

So in this case, $array2 came from the database, and $array1 is given. So how can I compare these two arrays in order to get this array back: $arraynew = Array ( [0] => tesla )?

Note:
So far I have tried this:

```
            $query = "SELECT name FROM tagsbreedables WHERE idTagCategory = 6";
            $result10 = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

            if (mysqli_num_rows($result10) > 0) {
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result10)) {
                    $bloem = $datas4['name'] = $row;

                    print_r($row);

                    $subarray = array_column($bloem,'name');

                    print_r($array3);

                }
            }


        $aMust = explode(" ", $_GET['q']);
        $searchTermBits = array();
        foreach ($aMust as $term) {
            $term = trim($term);
            if (!empty($term)) {
                $searchTermBits[] = "$term";
            }
        }
        $matches = $searchTermBits;
        $test = array($subarray, $matches);



        foreach ($test as $key => $subarray) {
            foreach ($subarray as $subsubarray) {
                foreach ($matches as $match) {
                    if ($subsubarray == $match) {
                        $finalarr[$key][] = $subsubarray;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        print_r($finalarr[0]);

        $pindakaas = implode('","',$finalarr[0]);
        echo $pindakaas;
```

The code works great, it's just that I don't know how to get data from the database into $subarray... I just get Array ( ) Array ( ) ...for $array3

Comment: You can flatten the database array to a one dimensional array and then use array_intersect() on them. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php

Comment: But how do you flatten it? I tried it before, but I failed...

Answer (score 1):

if $array2 is an array of arrays like below

```
array(Array ( [name] => tesla ) Array ( [name] => bmw ) Array ( [name] => opel ))
```

you can use the function `array_column` to get the values from a single column, in this case `name`.

```
$array3 = array_column($array2,'name')
```

the above should give you

```
array(0=>tesla,1=>bmw,2=>opel)
```

you can then use `array_intersect` to compare them

```
$arraynew = array_intersect($array1,$array3);
```

Comment: it doesn't work. I think the problem is because I use a while loop to get the data out of the database to put in $array2. So if I follow your code, I get Array ( [name] => tesla) Array ( ) Array ( [name] => bmw) Array ( )